# Civicrm on mariadb with data encryption

Tags: mariadb

is there any insights on installing civicrm on mariadb with data encryption turned on? Is it workable? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this, i ended up using LUKS to encrypt harddisk where mysql lived.  CIVICRM didn't seem to mind it so far and performance doesn't seem impacted.

Answer (score 1):

Logging tables until recently wouldn't be supported. If your install is older and you have logging turned on you might need to update the engine for the logging tables to InnoDB.

Otherwise I think it would just be regular system administration stuff not specific to CiviCRM.

But for me the issue with at-rest encryption has always been that storing the keys on the same server defeats the purpose, unless you're willing to password protect them and also not store the password on the server, i.e. manually start mysql any time the server needs rebooting and manually provide the password, and that may not even be doable depending on the hosting setup.

I see there is an eperi gateway plugin for mariadb which I was unaware of. That seems interesting.

Comment: Thanks Demerit!  Your post actually prompted me to look at eperi and other solutions which i later did a setup with ecryptFS.  there is also another promising solution Acra: https://github.com/cossacklabs/acra