# CIVICRM with MYSQL encrypted on ecryptfs

Tags: mysql

I managed to have CIVICRM (5.15.2 on WP 5.0.7 on Ubuntu 18) running on MySQL (5.7.28) from an encrypted mount via ecryptfs.  Currently only the mysql files are in the encrypted mount and it's running a few days now and all seems good.  I would like to check whether there are experiences from similar setup and whether there would be issues to anticipate ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking to your other question which is similar but slightly different since it's about using encryption that's natively supported by mariadb: [Civicrm on mariadb with data encryption](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31439/civicrm-on-mariadb-with-data-encryption/31443#31443).

For this question, I have used a similar tool `encfs` once for a **non-civi** setup to put the mysql files on an encrypted partition and it worked fine but the problem I had was the same as in the other post, that it partly defeats the purpose if you have to store the keys/password unencrypted on the same server, or else you can't do unattended reboots. It's a trade-off.

Comment: Thanks!  I have thought about that problem and did a script to activate the reboot via SSH with the password but otherwise the password would not be present on the server during operation.  So the window where the password is present on the server is reduce to just minutes.  The script of course will need to be in a trusted server but can be activated by cron.  A normal reboot on the CIVICRM server will render the database unusable as it is encrypted.